# how to get free space of unc path in java code?

Tags: java, file

I want to know the free space on UNC path(network path like \server\foldername) using java.
I found a sample to know the free space on local drive:

```
import java.io.File;  

public class GetFreeSpace  {  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        File file = new File("C:\\Hello.txt");  
        long value = file.getFreeSpace();  
        System.out.println("Total free space available in the file is "+value+" B");  
   }  
}
```

But this doesn't work for UNC path.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, because `File.getFreeSpace()` was introduced in Java 6, which means your application will not be executable on earlier platforms.

Regarding your question though, JVM can give you space for any UNC path (read [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#partName)). I guess you just missed to escape the backlashes in the `File` constructor. Here's an example of usage:

```
System.out.println(new File("\\\\192.168.0.1\\share").getFreeSpace());
```

returning the amount of bytes `9996869632`.